# How to send URL id from Asp.net View to Controller using Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want send the data from asp.net MVC View to my controller using Ajax.i can send the data to controller from text boxes.. the problem is how to add the URL id to post data in Controller using Ajax. please see the below code

**My URL**

```
http://localhost:20487/MyController/MyMethod/1
```

**My Script**

```
//Save if valid
            if (isAllValid) {
                var data = {
                    //project_id: $('#project_id').val().trim(),
                    project_id= *I want get the ID from Above URL*
                    title: $('#title').val().trim(),
                    description : $('#description').val().trim(),
                    ProjComponentActivities: componentActivities
                }

                $(this).val('Please wait...');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ProjectComponent/SaveComponent',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (d) {
                        //check is successfully save to database 
                        if (d.status == true) {
                            //will send status from server side
                            alert('Successfully done.');
                            //clear form
                            componentActivities = [];
                            //$('#project_id').val('');
                            $('#title').val('');
                            $('#componentActivities').empty();
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('Failed');
                        }
                        $('#submit').val('Save');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error. Please try again.');
                        $('#submit').val('Save');
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

**My Method**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveComponent(OrderVM O)
    {

        bool status = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (Entities db = new Entities())
            {
                ProjComponent ProjComponent = new ProjComponent { project_id = O.project_id, title = O.title, description = O.description };
                foreach (var i in O.ProjComponentActivities)
                {
                    ProjComponent.ProjComponentActivity.Add(i);
                }
                db.ProjComponents.Add(ProjComponent);
                db.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }
```

Comment: i added my methode code

Comment: In My method i need the Project_id value  to be posted from URL  .

Comment: MyMethod ==== public JsonResult SaveComponent(OrderVM O)

Comment: I post data to this method, in real the method MyMethod does not exist and i put thatu URL as example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just get the projectId parameter, you can simply append the following code to your JavaScript code:

```
@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["YOUR PROJECT ID PARAM"]
```

You will replace the parameter name with the  correct parameter name in the URL, ex: id as configured in URL Routing.

The other way is to use the same line of code to fill a hidden field value and later use this value directly in your JavaScript method

Comment: how to append that     inside instead ot project_ id   ----> var data = {
                        //project_id: $('#project_id').val().trim(),

                        title: $('#title').val().trim(),
                        description : $('#description').val().trim(),
                        ProjComponentActivities: componentActivities
                    }

Comment: project_id= "@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["YOUR PROJECT ID PARAM"]";

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`project_id= <%=Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]%>`

But please take note it's only work if your Js is in the View.
Else , your can store it in a ViewBag or some javascript object...